# Python increment pulling from an array in a loop

Tags: python, increment

I am trying to create something that would

- Read a file
- Separate ever thing into an array
- Use the first string in the array and do something
- After done go back to the second array and do something
- Keep repeating this process until the array is done.

So far I have

```
users = open('users.txt', "r")
userL = users.read().splitlines()
```

What I want it to do exactly is open the text file, which is already separated 1 line per string, then have the Python part put that into an array, get the first string and set that into a variable. From there the variable will be used in a URL for xbox.com.

After it checks it I will have some JSON read the page and see if the gamertag list I have is being used, if it is being used it will go back to the array and go to the second string and check. This needs to be a constant loop of checking gamertags. If it does find a gamertag in the array (From the text file) that isn't used, it will save that to another text file entitled "available gametags" and keep moving on.

What I want it to do (requested in comments)

- Open Program
- Have it read a text file of usernames I have created
- Have the program test each program at the end of the gamertag viewer link for xbox
- JSON read the page and if it contains info that the name is taken it goes back to the list and uses the next gamertag on the page.
- Keeps doing this
- Logs all the gamertags that worked and saves to a text file.
- Exits

The problem in doing that is I don't know how to go back to the file and access the line after the one it just tested and continue this pattern until the file is completely read.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: So basically you want a decent gamertag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do whatever with the line
```

For example, to achieve your goal here, you might do something like this:

```
# import our required modules
import json
import urllib2

# declare some initial variables
input_file = "users.txt"
output_file = "available_tags.txt"
available_tags = [] # an empty list to hold our available gamertags

# open the file
with open(input_file) as input_f:
    # loop through each line
    for line in input_f:
        # strip any new line character from the line
        tag = line.strip()
        # set up our URL and open a connection to the API
        url = "http://360api.chary.us/?gamertag=%s" % tag
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        # load the returned data as a JSON object
        data = json.loads(u.read())
        # check if the gamertag is available
        if not data['GamertagExists']:
            # print it and add it to our list of available tags if so
            print "Tag %s is available." % tag
            available_tags.append(tag)
        else:
            print "Tag %s is not available." % tag #otherwise

# check that we have at least one valid tag to store
if len(available_tags) > 0:
    # open our output file
    with open(output_file, "w") as output_f:
            # loop through our available tags
            for tag in available_tags:
                # write each one to the file
                output_f.write("%s\n" % tag)
else:
    print "No valid tags to be written to output file."
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the notations to, I am new to Python so this helped me a lot.

Comment: how would I implement another file to read into this statement?

Comment: To read a second, or infinite number of input files, create a list of filenames and loop through it, executing the block of code I've already written for each file.  Be sure to reindent the current block of code.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, the following code will read a whole file from start to finish in that order, and print each line individually:

```
with open(r"path/to.file.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        print(line) # Python 2.7: Use 'print line' instead
```

If you need to remove the trailing new lines from each string, use `.strip()`.

To write data to a file, use something like the following:

```
with open(r"path/to/out/file.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.writelines(data_to_write)
```

Comment: I understand how to do that part, except now I want it to read each line that was outputted one at a time and whenever one is read set it into a variable and keep switching variables out

Comment: That is what the for loop does, and I would suggest you read up on them.  I put together a program which does what you want and will add it to my own answer.  I don't know if you're wanting to use the same API that I did, and I still think you should read up on control-flow statements such as loops because they're pretty fundamental to programming in any language.